# Adding Button from loop into UIScrollView

Tags: ios

i am writing this code to create buttons from loop and adding them into UIScrollView but somehow its not working , please can someone help.
the code is

```
 scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc]init];
[self createurdulistfordisplay];


for(int i = 1;i<[urdulist count];i++)
{
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];


    [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [button addTarget:self
               action:@selector(playurduaudio:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

    button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0 + (30*i), 213.0, 46.0);

    [scroll addSubview:button];
}
```

Comment: where are you adding the scroll view? You should be setting its frame for it to be displayed. Give more details.

Comment: add scroll to self.view

Comment: thanx i forgot to add the scrollview in frame ...thansx Rakesh and Ravindra

Answer (score 0):

I think you have forgotten to add scroll to view. add like his at last line

```
[self.view addSubView:scroll];
```

Here you have created scroll but not added to your view that means until you adds this scrollView to main view i.e. to self.view ,you will not get it display on screen